# RxSwift: Using BehaviorRelay I get this error: Instance method 'concatMap' requires that '[Int]' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'

Tags: rx-swift, xcode11, ios13.2, swift5

I'm trying to use `concatMap` on `BehaviorRelay` but I'm getting this error:

```
Instance method 'concatMap' requires that '[Int]' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'
```

This is my implementation:

```
class MyClass{

    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var subject: BehaviorRelay<[Int]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [1,2,3,4,5])


    func doSomething() {
        subject.asObservable().concatMap { $0 }
            .subscribe { print($0) }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on this line:

```
subject.asObservable().concatMap { $0 }
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or how can fix this error on my implementation ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is conceptual. It doesn't make any sense to use concatMap on an array of Ints. The error is basically telling you that an array of Ints is *not* an Observable. There aren't any Observables to concat here.

You need to go back and think about what you are trying to accomplish and find the right operator for the job.